# Only pass arguments that aren't None to Flask's url_for

Tags: python, flask

I am currently trying to set up a search in Flask using keywords and the form GET method.

To handle pagination, I have to pass all the keywords for the filters to the `url_for` for the next or last pages. However, sometimes these keywords aren't needed and just clutter up the url bar.

```py
{{ url_for(request.endpoint, page=pagination.next_num, searchTerm=searchTerm, blendLicense=blendLicense, renderEngine=renderEngine, blenderVersion=blenderVersion) }}
```

Is there a way to only pass the keywords that aren't `None` so as not to clutter up the URL bar? If it were only one keyword to check, I'd use an `if else` block, but there are many keywords to check.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the call like this:

```
kwargs = dict(searchTerm=searchTerm,
              blendLicense=blendLicense,
              renderEngine=renderEngine,
              blenderVersion=blenderVersion)

url_for(request.endpoint, page=pagination.next_num, **kwargs)
```

This works same as the code in your question.
But now you can conveniently filter out a default value such as `None`:

```
def filter_default(kwargs):
    return {k: v
            for k, v in kwargs.items()
            if v}
```

(Or, use `if v is not None` if values like empty string might be present.)

Apply that filtering function to the dictionary before passing it in.

EDIT

```
{{ url_for(request.endpoint,
           page=pagination.next_num,
           **filter_default(dict(searchTerm=searchTerm,
                                 blendLicense=blendLicense,
                                 renderEngine=renderEngine,
                                 blenderVersion=blenderVersion))) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

`url_for` already ignores keywords that are `None`. You don't need to do anything on top of that.

```py
@app.route("/search")
def search():
    ...
```

```
url_for("search", name="Flask", page=2))
"/search?name=Flask&page=2"
url_for("search", name="Flask", page=None))
"/search?name=Flask"
```